# Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties Formular

Tags: java, sql-server, google-app-engine, jdbc

Something very strange happened, I'm doing a web application in java with app engine and SQL server using rest services, everything works apparently fine, but only once, that is, I have an endpoint that connects to a database and runs a Store Procedure, when I connect to the endpoint for the first time it works correctly, but when I do it a second time it throws me the following error:

> Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

It is very strange, because I have other applications that connect to the same database, which also use app engine, which use the same sql driver and have no problem. I have can't to see what is different about this one.

Code:

```
@Override
public void register() throws DatabaseException {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xxx.xxx.xx;databaseName=mydatabase", Config.USER, Config.PASSWORD);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement
            = connection.prepareStatement("execute store_procedure")) {

        preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        throw new DatabaseException();
    }
}
```

Pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but afaik, `characterEncoding` is not a valid connection property for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver (at least, it is not listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties)

Comment: Your problem is likely one of _"blocked by a firewall"_.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks, I did not know

Comment: I do not think it's the firewall, because the first connection works well, I've already reviewed it and it seems to be fine

Comment: What  is this "first connection"? You mentioned a different application that could connect, is that what you mean? Maybe that application is configured correctly or its IP address is allowed through your firewall while this application is not.

Comment: And can you comment on whether this is a deployed GAE app or a local development environment?